# Using Gridview and Button in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I tried add button below gridview in linearlayout at following code. But when i execute my app i only see gridview there is no button item. So it may basic mistake but i can't see it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#2a2a2a"
         >
            <GridView 
                    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnWidth="150dp"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:gravity="center"></GridView>
            <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button1" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="50dp" 
                    android:text="@string/cam_string" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the orientation of your `LinearLayout` to `vertical`.  I suspect you're not seeing the Button because the GridView takes up all horizontal space, then the LinearLayout adds the Button in a place off the screen that's not visible.  You also may want to change the `layout_height` of the GridView to "0dip" and give it the `android:layout_weight=1' attribute so that it will fill all space except that taken up by the Button.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the suggested Solution by others you can try the alternative using relative layout.

You can use a `RelativeLayout` for this purpose instead of LinearLayout.

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#2a2a2a" >

          <GridView 
                android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="150dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"></GridView>
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:text="@string/cam_string" />

          </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Raghunandan it works but button move on the gridview layer.

Comment: i din;t understand your comment.