# GridView breaks while scrolling?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am developing an app the will show the girls fashion categories. I tried to display categories in grid view. But when I test the app, Grid View is breaking while I am scrolling it. And following are my codes. Please help me in this. thanks in advance.

[image]

single_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"/>

<TextView
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
activity_browse.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.user.beautyworld.BrowseActivity">


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` for this purpose instead of `LinearLayout`.

single_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#2a2a2a" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"/>

<TextView
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_browse.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#2a2a2a" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This answer was already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219742/using-gridview-and-button-in-linearlayoutStartseite/).

Comment: still i'm facing the problem